# What should I use for string resource instead of TextView

Tags: android, string, textview

If I do this:

```
TextView coppertv = (TextView) findViewById(R.string.copper);
```

I get no errors but whenever I try to change the string using .setText() it gives me an exception telling me

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

I would like to know what I should use instead of TextView for string resource. I tried

```
String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);
```

as suggested by someone on another thread but then I cannot use .setText();

Answer (score 0):

You should find your TextView by its id.

```
TextView coppertv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.copper);
```

instead of

```
TextView coppertv = (TextView) findViewById(R.string.copper);
```

Comment: It's in the string.xml file, not activity_main.xml so it doesn't have that kind of id to my knowledge.

Comment: @Tertles You shouldn't put textviews in your strings.xml. You only use your strings.xml file for declaring string values. You should never set the Strings.xml file as a view.
Put your textview in your activity_main.xml, assign an id to it and use the code I provided.

Comment: What I mean is that I use @string/copper for in the activity_main.xml file. I will take your advice and change that, thank you.